# Remove Intersecting Instances (Geometry Nodes)

Tags: modeling, modifiers, geometry-nodes

In a geo nodes setup, there a way to not place instances where there are already instances **without** using poisson disk?

I am using a setup that turns a mesh's geometry into a volume, then distributes points in that volume. I am scattering instances on those points but I am using different types of instances, and they are collecting on the same points, creating z-fighting.

Comment: (A mesh is turned into a volume, and points are scattered in that volume. Then, instances (bricks) are placed on those points.)

Comment: A possible solution would be to only place the blue/red brick instances on the top of the mesh (upward facing normals), but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Your GN setup is much too complex for me to get a quick overview, but Joey Carlino made a good tutorial on how to "lego-fy" things in Blender... and he had no overlapping problem if I remember it correctly: [Lego anything with this NEW Blender geometry nodes feature](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LrEHoaq6QFE)

Comment: I followed that tutorial but added to his node setup to include more bricks. He only used a 1x1 brick while I am using 3 different types of bricks, and thus 3 different sets of instances.